# Explain ntpdate debugging output

Tags: ntpdate

May I know what is meant by "reference time" in the `ntpdate -d` output?

```
reference time:    d5cff417.1a961fff  Tue, Sep  3 2013  7:37:27.103
```

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Network Time Protocol](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc958) Docs:

Reference Timestamp:

This is a 64-bit timestamp established by the server or client host as the timestamp (presumably obtained from a reference clock) most recently used to update the local clock.  If the local clock has never been synchronized, the value is zero.